# Is there a reason why common R data types/container are indexed so differently?

Tags: r

common container types used in R are data.tables, data.frames, matrices and lists (probably more?!).
All these storage types have slightly different rules for indexing.
Let's say we have a simple `dataset` with named columns:

```
name1 name2
1     11
2     12
...     ...
10     20
```

We now put this data in every container accordingly. If I want to index the number 5 which is in the `name1` column it goes as follows:

```
lists:        dataset[['name1']][5]
-> why the double brackets?!?!

data frames:  dataset$name1[5] or dataset[5,'name1']
-> here are two options possible, why the ambiguity?!?

data table:   dataset$name1[5]
-> why is it here only one possibility
```

I often stumbled upon this problem and coming from python this is something very odd. It furthermore leads to extremely tedious debuging. In python this is solved in a very uniform way where indexing is pretty much standard across lists,numpy arrays, pandas data frames, etc.

Comment: R is derived from S, which was a domain specific language for statistics, and like many DSL's, S was not carefully designed according to some theoretical principle. Why does R/S have this or that particular feature? I dunno, it seemed like a good idea at the time. There's not much more to say about it. The same can be said for Matlab/Octave, SAS, SPSS, Scilab, etc etc., some of which are less terrible than others.

Comment: All the 2-d data structure will work fine with `x[5, 1]` or `x[5, "name1"]`---including 2-d  data structures you don't mention like `matrix` or `tbl_df`. 2-d data structures are incredibly common, so it makes sense to have special handling for them. Lists are not (necessarily) 2-d, so there's no reasonable expectation to have the 2-d indexing patterns work. (With the caveat that the non-base `data.table` and `tbl_df` change the default `drop` behavior and don't simplify the structure of the result, by  default.)

Comment: And why do you think there's only one possibility with data table? If we call the data.table version `x_dt`, all of these will work: `x_dt[5, 1]`, `x_dt[5, "name1"]`, (returning 1x1 data.tables) or `x_dt$name1[5]`, `x_dt[["name1"]][5]`, `x_dt[[1]][5]` (returning the 1-element vector 5.

Comment: And if you're interested in why `data.table` returns 1x1 data.tables for the first syntax, that's the very first question addressed in the [data.table Beginner FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#j-num)... essentially `data.table` corrects the "ambiguity" making `x_dt$name1[5]` different from `x_dtt[5, "name1"]`, in that one returns a value, and the other returns a 1x1 data.table.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.frame` is a `list` with equal elements having equal length.  We use `$` or `[[` to extract the `list` elements or else it would still be a `list` with one element

Answer (score 1):

You reference the `data.frame` example in R and then go on to say you are used to pandas, except these have direct, standard equivalents in pandas for the exact same purpose, so unsure where the confusion comes from.

`dataset$name1[5]`    -> `dataset['name1'][5]` or `dataset.name1[5]`

`dataset[5, 'name1']` -> `dataset.loc[5, 'name1']`

Answer (score 1):

Using the definitions in the Note at the end these all work and give the same answer.

```
L[["name1"]][5]
DF[["name1"]][5]
DT[["name1"]][5]

L$name1[5]
DF$name1[5]
DT$name1[5]
```

It seems not unreasonable that a data frame which is conceptually a 2d object can take two subscripts whereas a list which is one dimensional takes one.

[[ and [ have different meanings so I am not sure consistency plays a role here.

### Note

```
L <- list(name1 = 1:10, name2 = 11:20)
DF <- as.data.frame(L)

library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(DF)
```

Comment: I guess I am yet oblivious as to why it is necessary to have the differentiation between `[` and `[[` for lists. For me `[[` is always preferable, as most times you want to access the content of a list element, rather than pointing to said element within the list.

Comment: [[ gives an element and has the class of the element whereas [ gives a sublist and has class "list" so they are different things.  If you did not have [ then you would need some other way to get a sublist.